# Find maximal x^y smaller than number

Tags: algorithm, math

I have number A (build from digits 0,1,2,3). I want to find the smallest x and y, that if I do x^y i got the biggest number smaller than A

x^y <= A x^y is maximal

Plus x and y must not be decimal numbers, only "integers"

For example:

```
A = 7 => x^y = 2^2
A = 28 => x^y = 3^3
A = 33 => x^y = 2^5
```

etc

**Edit:**
As izomorphius suggested in comment, it will have always solution for x = A and y = 1. But that is not desirable result. I want x and y to be as much close numbers, as it can be.

Comment: Please add more to the statement. It is obvious that if y=1 you always have the option x = A and y = 1.

Comment: Also, what does "the smallest x and y" mean? That's not a mathematical statement.

Comment: x and y are integers or can they be floats?

Comment: If A is not a non-trivial exact power, and there is a pair x and y both of which are much smaller than A, with x^y = A-1, which should be chosen? If there are two pairs x1, y1 and x2, y2, with one having the smaller largest number and the other having the larger power, which should be chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naive solution could be:

The "closest yet not higher" number to A by doing `a^y` for some constant `a` is:

`afloor(log_a(A))` [where `log_a(A)` is the logarithm with base `a` of `A`, which can be calculated as `log(A)/log(a)` in most programming languages]

By iterating all `a`s in range `[2,A)` you can find this number.

This solution is `O(A * f(A))` where `f(A)` is your pow/log complexity

**P.S.** If you want your exponent (`y`) be larger then 1, you can simply iterate in range `[2,sqrt(A)]` - it will reduce the time complexity to `O(sqrt(A) * f(A))` - and will get you only numbers with an exponent larger then 1.

Comment: This solution is uneccesarily naive.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are asking, but I will try to guess.

We first solve the equation `z^z = a` for a real number `z`. Let `u` and `v` be `z` rounded down and up, respectively. Among the three candidates `(u,u)`, `(v,u)`, `(u,v)` we choose the largest one that does not exceed `a`.

Example: Consder the case `a = 2000`. We solve `z^z = 2000` by numerical methods (see below) to get an approximate solution `z = 4.8278228255818725`. We round down an up to obtain `u = 4` and `v = 5`. We now have three candidates, `4^4 = 256`, `4^5 = 1023` and `5^4 = 625`. They are all smaller than `2000`, so we take the one that gives the largest answer, which is `x = 4`, `y = 5`.

Here is Python code. The function `solve_approx` does what you want. It works well for `a >= 3`. I am sure you can cope with the cases `a = 1` and `a = 2` by yourself.

```
import math

def solve(a):
    """"Solve the equation x^x = a using Newton's method"""
    x = math.log(a) / math.log(math.log(a)) # Initial estimate
    while abs (x ** x - a) > 0.1:
        x = x - (x ** x - a) / (x ** x * (1 + math.log(x)))
    return x

def solve_approx(a):
    """"Find two integer numbers x and y such that x^y is smaller than
    a but as close to it as possible, and try to make x and y as equal
    as possible."""
    # First we solve exactly to find z such that z^z = a
    z = solve(a)
    # We round z up and down
    u = math.floor(z)
    v = math.ceil(z)
    # We now have three possible candidates to choose from:
    # u ** zdwon, v ** u, u ** v
    candidates = [(u, u), (v, u), (u, v)]
    # We filter out those that are too big:
    candidates = [(x,y) for (x,y) in candidates if x ** y <= a]
    # And we select the one that gives the largest result
    candidates.sort(key=(lambda key: key[0] ** key[1]))
    return candidates[-1]
```

Here is a little demo:

```
 >>> solve_approx(5)
 solve_approx(5)
 (2, 2)
 >>> solve_approx(100)
 solve_approx(100)
 (3, 4)
 >>> solve_approx(200)
 solve_approx(200)
 (3, 4)
 >>> solve_approx(1000)
 solve_approx(1000)
 (5, 4)
 >>> solve_approx(1000000)
 solve_approx(1000000)
 (7, 7)
```

Comment: But that doesn't fulfil `A = 33 => x^y = 2^5`. How the possible conflict between maximising `x^y` and minimising `|x - y|` is to be resolved isn't specified, however.

Comment: Indeed, it is not specified, and since I cannot read minds, I did it so that the difference between 'x' and 'y' is always at most 1. I am sure there are other readings of the problem.